# Network printer problem with 12.04

Tags: printing, samba

I had an HP LaserJet 3030 printer connected to an Ubuntu box.  It worked fine with 11.10.  I was able to print from Ubuntu as well as from Windows and Mac from the home network.

About a month or so ago, I upgraded 11.10 to 12.04, then things started to falling apart.  My Windows 7 laptop couldn't print to the printer any more.

Today, I installed many updates on 12.04, hoping that would fix the printing problem.  Unfortunately, it made the situation much worse.  Now not only my Windows 7 laptop won't print, my XP desktop won't print either.

Every time I print something from the Windows computer, the Ubuntu box logs an error message in `/var/log/samba/log.'machineName'` as:

```
_spoolss_OpenPrinterEx: Cannot open a printer handle for printer \\server.
```

It is interesting that it uses the server name as the printer, not the `\\server\xyzprinter` as the printer name.

Anyone had a similar problem?  Anyway to work around the problem?

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem. The real reason for this problem is that some times a Windows Client has a "ghost port" configured, that's been lost or misconfigured. The clear evidence is that the Windows system is asking the server for a printer without the printer name.

The sollution is simple: go to the Printers and Faxes control panel on Windows Box, remove the offending printer and add it again.

Comment: If you can, try to add some screen-shot (press the *Impr-Pant* key) to guide the user what exactly do.

Answer (score 0):

I know of a Linux fix for HP Printers.

HPLIP:

- [Supported Devices](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/supported_devices/index.html)
- [Download](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/downloads.html)

Hopefully that will help you.